# How can I use read-csv-file to read from a string instead?

Tags: csv, racket, htdp

The [2htdp/batch-io](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpbatch-io.html) library contains the useful [`read-csv-file`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpbatch-io.html?q=port-%3E#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fbatch-io..rkt%29._read-csv-file%29%29) procedure for reading a CSV file into a list. It takes a filename as its argument. Unfortunately, it does not take a string containing CSV as its argument. Suppose I have a CSV in a string variable and I want to use `read-csv-file` to parse it. Is there a way to avoid saving the CSV to a file just to be able to parse the CSV?

The documentation says:

> reads the standard input device (until closed) or the content of file f and produces it as a list of lists of comma-separated values.

The standard input feature could probably be exploited to achieve this, but I don't know how to proceed with this idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a way to make [`read-csv-file`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpbatch-io.html?q=port-%3E#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fbatch-io..rkt%29._read-csv-file%29%29) read from a string instead:

```
> (require 2htdp/batch-io)
> (define csv-string "one,one,one\ntwo,two,two")
> (parameterize ([current-input-port (open-input-string csv-string)])
    (read-csv-file 'stdin))
'(("one" "one" "one") ("two" "two" "two"))
```

This works by changing the standard input to be the CSV string.

@Ryan Schaefer's answer about [`simulate-file`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpbatch-io.html?q=port-%3E#%28form._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fbatch-io..rkt%29._simulate-file%29%29) is great, but I feel a bit uncomfortable with using functionality that is still "under development" and not properly documented. As `simulate-file`'s documentation says:

> Note: this form is under development and will be documented in a precise manner after it is finalized and useful for a wide audience.

Comment: Just a note for people worried that changing the standard input here might break things, they're using `parameterize` for just that reason: it only will make that change in the code block bounded by that call, and outside of that block, it will be as if nothing changed.

Answer (score 3):

The 2htdp libraries are meant for beginners are thus are less flexible than other csv libraries. Therefore, you have two options:

1. `batch-io` provides `simulate-file` which is something similar to what you want, but nothing as clean as wrapping your string in a function which makes it into a file like object:

```
> (simulate-file read-csv-file "test,test,test")
(list (list "test" "test" "test"))
```

2. Use `csv-reading` (`csv-reading` must be downloaded but just `(require csv-reading)` and continue through the errors it gives you):

```
#lang racket
(require csv-reading)
> (csv->list "test,test,test")
(list (list "test" "test" "test"))
```

If `batch-io` were more general it would be take in a `string?` or an `input-port?` but it does not.

Comment: I am very surprised that the only built-in CSV reading functionality is inside a HtDP library!